# How to put bracket around the number of a theorem?

Tags: numbering, ntheorem

What I want is like this:

> (1.1) Theorem. *blabla...*

I have used ntheorem package to interchange the number of a theorem and its name. Then, how to put the bracket around the number?

```
\documentclass{book}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage[amsmath,thmmarks]{ntheorem}
  \theoremstyle{change}
  \theorembodyfont{\itshape}
   \newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]

\begin{document}
 \chapter{A Chapter}
 \section{A section}
   \begin{thm}
     A theorem.
   \end{thm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal test case](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/html/) that shows the current state? Would save some time for supporters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define a new theorem style `mychange`

```
\makeatletter 
 \newtheoremstyle{mychange}%
  {\item[\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont (##2)\ ##1\theorem@separator]}%
  {\item[\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont (##2)\ ##1\ (##3)\theorem@separator]}
\makeatother
```

and use

```
\theoremstyle{mychange}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{book}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage[amsmath,thmmarks]{ntheorem}

\makeatletter 
 \newtheoremstyle{mychange}%
  {\item[\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont (##2)\ ##1\theorem@separator]}%
  {\item[\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont (##2)\ ##1\ (##3)\theorem@separator]}
\makeatother

  \theoremstyle{mychange}
  \theorembodyfont{\itshape}
   \newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]

\begin{document}
 \chapter{A Chapter}
 \section{A section}
   \begin{thm}
     A theorem.
   \end{thm}
\end{document}
```

[image]