# Adding parentheses to number of theorem

Tags: amsthm

I am trying to add parentheses to number of definition. I found such [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/234765/how-to-put-bracket-around-the-number-of-a-theorem), but it doesn't work for me: it gives me error "Missing number treated as zero"

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{stix}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\setcounter{section}{-1}

\newtheorem{df}{Def.}[subsection]
\newtheorem{nt}[df]{Note}
\newtheorem{st}[df]{Statement}

\makeatletter 
    \newtheoremstyle{eqStyle}%
        {\item[\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont (##2)\ ##1\theorem@separator]}%
        {\item[\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont (##2)\ ##1\ (##3)\theorem@separator]}
\makeatother

\theoremstyle{eqStyle}
\newtheorem{eqStyle}[df]{}

%next code.
```

I don't know what does it mean. I found that `\newtheoremstyle` should have more parameters, but at example in link, which I have put, it has less parameters and, as member said, it worked. Please help.

Thanks Mike.

EDIT:

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{stix}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\setcounter{section}{-1}

\def\n{\newline}
\def\q#1{"#1"}
\def\com#1{{\color[rgb]{0.25, 0.25, 0.25}//#1//}}
\def\aks#1{{\large Aksjomat \underline{#1}}}
\def\bel#1#2{#1 : #2}
\def\kon#1#2{#1 \wedge #2}
\def\imp#1#2{#1 \Rightarrow #2}
\def\rown#1#2{#1 \Leftrightarrow #2}
\def\curly#1{\left\{#1\right\}}
\def\rou#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\FA#1{\bigwedge\limits_{#1}}
\def\Class{\underline{Class}}
\def\Univ{\underline{Univ}}
\def\Null{\underline{null}}
\def\Char{\underline{Char}}
\def\Var{\underline{Var}}



\newtheorem{df}{Definicja}[subsection]
\newtheorem{nt}[df]{Uwaga}
\newtheorem{st}[df]{Twierdzenie}

%\makeatletter 
%   \newtheoremstyle{eqStyle}%
%       {\item[\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont (##2)\ ##1\theorem@separator]}%
%       {\item[\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont (##2)\ ##1\ (##3)\theorem@separator]}
%\makeatother

%\theoremstyle{eqStyle}
\newtheorem{eqStyle}[df]{}

\begin{document}
\section{Intro}
\subsection{Sub 1}
\begin{eqStyle}
\label{013}
\n\n $123 = 100 + 23$
\end{eqStyle}
\end{document}
```

This works. When I uncomment the middle lines, I get error

```
Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.41 \newtheorem{eqStyle}
                         [df]{}
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say it doesnt work? Because, the solution that you linked works fine for me. Also, please add a fully-compilable `MWE`.

Comment: You're trying to use `ntheorem` syntax with `amsthm`.

Comment: Thank you. How should I do this? I study LaTeX from yesterday.

Ok, than you very much. I changed amsthm to ntheorem is usepackage and it works, THANKS!!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because solved on comments, only loading the appropriate package.